# Заменить подстроки на Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Задача простая, найти в строке **USD**, **EUR** или любой другой ключ валют в мире и поменять их на знаки (**$**, **€**) соответственно.

Не знаю, как создать подобную функцию красивым кодом, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри в сторону регулярок, там есть нужные тебе методы

```
var str: NSMutableString = "Hello fucking $ World, please give me more €"
let ignoreArray = ["\\$", "€"]
let template = ["\\$" : "USD", "€" : "EUR"]
do {
    for pattern in ignoreArray {
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.length)
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        regex.replaceMatchesInString(str, options: NSMatchingOptions.ReportCompletion, range: range, withTemplate: template[pattern]!)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}

print(str) // "Hello fucking USD World, please give me more EUR"
```

[Replacing Strings Using Regular Expressions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW31)

Comment: Разве регулярными выражениями можно сделать замену сразу множества подстрок? Сначала тоже о них подумал, но составлять регулярное выражение для всех символов как-то слишком громоздко.

Comment: Можно в цикле подменять паттерн, по которому парсится. Привел пример в ответе.

Comment: судя по тэгам, автор вопроса хотел objC :)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko главное суть, на obj-c тут и переписывать нечего

Comment: ну если ответ принят, то видимо автор достаточно в курсе как это переписать.

Answer (score 2):

Так же можно использовать:

```
NSString *currencyCode = @"EUR";
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:currencyCode];
NSString *currencySymbol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:currencyCode]];
NSLog(@"Currency Symbol : %@", currencySymbol);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете в виду простую замену подстрок на Obj-C? Если да, то это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
    NSString *temp = @"35 EUR, 56USD, 32.6EUR, etc...";
    temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"EUR" withString:@"€"];
    temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"USD" withString:@"$"];
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
```

Если нужно многоразовое решение с возможностью загрузки большого числа символов откуда-нибудь из файла, то можно сделать ещё красивей:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dict[@"EUR"] = @"€";
    dict[@"USD"] = @"$";
    NSString *temp = @"35 EUR, 56USD, 32.6EUR, etc...";
    for (int i = 0; i < [dict count]; i++) {
        temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i] withString:[[dict allValues] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", temp);
```

**UPD:** ну и самый эффективный вариант, с единственным проходом строки:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    dict[@"EUR"] = @"€";
    dict[@"USD"] = @"$";
    dict[@"RUB"] = @"₽";
    dict[@"JPY"] = @"¥";
    NSString *string = @"EUR, over 9999 USD; no RUB, I wanna have JPY and 3.1415926535EUR";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < [string length] - 2) {
        NSString *symbol = dict[[string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 3)]];
        if (symbol) {
            NSString *before = (i > 0) ? ([string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, i)]) : @"";
            NSString *after = (i + 3 < [string length]) ? ([string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i + 3, [string length] - i - 3)]) : @"";
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",
                      before, symbol, after];
        }
        i++;
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

Результат: €, over 9999 $; no ₽, I wanna have ¥ and 3.1415926535€

Comment: код то, конечно, красивый, но если это реально надо сделать для сотни валют, то сто раз пройти через строку, если эта строка еще и тысячи символов...

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko верное замечание. В таком случае строку надо проходить один раз, вероятно, вручную, пытаясь отыскать подстроку в данной позиции. В принципе, если ключи валют всегда состоят из трёх символов (так ведь?), то не трудно сделать. Как время будет, допишу.